# Drupal Webform / CiviEvent showing private events and closed registration events

Tags: civievent, drupal, webform-civicrm

We are using Drupal Webforms to allow people to register for CiviEvents. We are using the Live Options setting for the Event Selection. Our issue is that we are seeing in the Live Options list events that are PRIVATE (not marked public) and events that have registration closed. The only way to stop them from showing is to make them inactive events. This then causes all schedule reminders to stop being sent.

Question:  Other than use Static Options, how to we make events that are private and/or no longer open for registration stop showing?

CiviCRM 4.7.6 and Drupal 7.51

Thanks!
Sheila

Answer (score 1):

If your organization can fund an hour or two of development via the [paid issue queue](https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue) we could get that filter added to the webform-civicrm module to prevent unwanted events from showing.

Comment: Thanks Coleman - let me confirm but Spry might do that. We are using Webforms for several clients for event registration.